# Sending a HTTP POST from frontend Typescript/React using axios to C# backend throws net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: c#, reactjs, typescript

So I am a beginner and I am trying to send HTTP POST request from a React/typescript frontend to a C# backend API.

When I start the function in the frontend, the following error gets thrown in the web console:

> AxiosError {message: 'Network Error', name: 'AxiosError', code:
> 'ERR_NETWORK', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}xhr.js:220
> POST http://localhost:7104/api/Authorisation/LogIn
> net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Here is my component in React:

```
import { Component } from "react"
import axios from 'axios'


export class MainPage extends Component<any, any>{

  constructor(props: string){
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      login: '',
      password: ''
    }
  }
  
  handleUsernameChange = (event: any) => {
    this.setState({
      login: event.target.value
    })
  }

  handlePasswordChange = (event:any) => {
    this.setState({
      password: event.target.value
    })
  }

  submitHandler = (event: any) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    console.log(this.state)
    axios.post('http://localhost:7104/api/Authorisation/LogIn', this.state)
    
      .then(response =>{
        console.log(response)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
      })
  }

  showLogin = () => {
  ...
  }

  render (){  
  return (
 ...
        <form className="login-section" onSubmit={this.submitHandler}>
          <button type="submit" className="left-button" id="left-button" onMouseOver={() => this.showLogin()} ><img className="log-in-icon" src="ICONS/log-in.png"/>Log In</button>
          <input id="userName-input" name="username" value={this.state.username} onChange={this.handleUsernameChange}/>
          <input id="password-input" name="password" value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handlePasswordChange} type="password"/>
        </form>
...
   )}
}
```

Here is the Program.cs from backend:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using RecipeDate.Application;
using RecipeDate.Infrastructure;
using RecipeDate.Infrastructure.Persistance;
using RecipeDate.Infrastructure.UserModels;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddInfrastructure(builder.Configuration);
builder.Services.AddApplication();

builder.Services.AddIdentity<UserRecipeDate, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(
    options => options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration.GetSection("Jwt:Issuer").Value,
        ValidAudience = builder.Configuration.GetSection("Jwt:Audiene").Value
    });

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                      policy =>
                      {
                          policy.WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000", "https://localhost:3000");
                          policy.AllowAnyHeader();
                          policy.AllowAnyMethod();
                      });
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

And here is the controller that I am calling (The LogIn one):

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using RecipeDate.Application.Services.Interfaces;
using RecipeDate.Infrastructure.UserModels;

namespace RecipeDate.API.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class AuthorisationController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IAuthorisationServices _authorisationServices;
        public AuthorisationController(IAuthorisationServices authorisationServices)
        {
            _authorisationServices = authorisationServices;
        }
        [EnableCors]
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("LogIn")]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task LogInAsync([FromBody]string login, string password)
        {
            await _authorisationServices.LogInUserAsync(login, password);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("Register")]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task RegisterAsync(UserDto user)
        {
            await _authorisationServices.RegisterUserAsync(user);
        }
    }
}
```

I will be grateful for any help as I am stuck with that for a while now!

Comment: I dont think you can have one parameter as `[FromBody]` and the other not.  You should create a POCO with those properties so you can have one param to the method and mark it `[FromBody]`

Comment: Neither of your controller methods are returning a response. It is far better for the controller methods to return `Task<IActionResult>` and each method to return `NoContent()`

Comment: @Jonesopolis You can decorate each parameter with a different [From] if you desire (you could have the password [FromRoute] for example.  I believe the default is [FromBody], so the result is the same, even if the code looks different.